# how to bring label and text box in one line in strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

my label appears on top and below it input box is displayed i want both on the same line.

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend style="color:red">Enter Details</legend><br />

    <div style="color:red">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" style="color:InfoBackground">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div><br/>

    <div class="editor-field" style="color:red">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" style="color: InfoBackground">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
    </div><br/>

    <div class="editor-label" style="color:red">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile_Number)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" style="color: InfoBackground">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile_Number)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile_Number)
    </div><br/>

    <div align="center"><input type=submit" value="submit" /></div>
</fieldset>
```

what changes must be done.Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know that the Div's are by default display:block.So if you want to show you lable or input etc inline then update that div style .Apply the following style to your div to you want to show in line.

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have you label wrapped in a div.  Div's are [default display:block.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)  That means they forces a new line.

Easiest thing to do is to place your @Html.LabelFor and @Html.EditorFor inside the same div and change your css to get the effect you want.